# Why aren't multiple tags created with each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I've got some data that looks like this

```
<data>
    <location>
        <type>main</type>
    </location>
    <location>
        <type>mailing</type>
    </location>
</data>
```

and then some code that looks like this

```
$('location',data).each(function(){

          var x='<table><tr><td>Type:</td><td>'+$(data).find('type').text()+'</td></tr></table>';
         $('#output').html(x);
});
```

The result I get from running this is

Type:   mainmailing

I don't understand why it isn't doing the following since for each location element it should run the code again, right?

Type:   main

Type:   mailing

Comment: use .append() instead of .html()

Answer (score 2):

Because you keep overriding the previous value.

`.html()` does not append to the content that is in there, it overrides it.

It is weird you are creating spearte tables and not just rows but the basic idea

```
var x='<table><tr><td>Type:</td><td>'+$(this).find('type').text()+'</td></tr></table>';
$('#output').append(x);
```

I would expect something more like

```
var table = "<table><tbody>";
$(data).find('location').each(function(){
   table += "<tr><th>Type:</th><td>'+$(this).find('type').text()+'</td></tr>';
});
table += "</tbody></table>";
$('#output').html(table);
```

Comment: But it's combining the two data values, not replacing them? I'm a bit confused

Comment: Additionally, you can use `.append();`

Comment: And besides IIRC `.html()` uses `.innerHTML` and shouldn't be used even if it would work.

Comment: @barit it was combineing them because you were not using `$(this)` in the each loop, you were referencing all of the type elements using `$(data)`

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I was able to get it working thanks to you and @sushanth

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be getting `Type: mainmailing`

cause you seem to be finding it in the whole of data and not the current location tag.

```
$(data).find('type').text()
```

supposed to be

```
$(this).find('type').text();
```

Also you **keep overriding** the values in each loop iteration.
Move the appending to the outside of the loop.

```
var x = '<table>'
$('location','data').each(function(){
     x +='<tr><td>Type:</td><td>'+$(this).find('type').text()+'</td></tr>';   
});
x += '</table>'
$('#output').html(x);
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/vvwHK/2/)**

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I was able to get it working

Comment: @barit.. Glad to have helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `append()` instead of `html()` and you should use the item you are currently processing inside `each()`.

```
var data = "<data><location><type>main</type></location><location><type>mailing</type></location></data>";

$('location', data).each(function(index, item) {
    var x = '<table><tr><td>Type:</td><td>' + $(item).find('type').text() + '</td></tr></table>';
    $('#output').append(x);
});​
```

Here's a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b69cr/).